# Typesetting Arabic Script with correct RTL Verso-Recto Order

Tags: xetex, arabic, bidi

I am typesetting a full Arabic ONLY book with XeTeX using LaTeXmk, the produced PDF when opened displays pages as if the book opens Left-to-Right as in Latin script, which is wrong, I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

This is the header of my latex file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
b5paper,
total={136mm,210mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
        bookmarksopen,
        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
        colorlinks=true,
        pagebackref,
        linkcolor=green
    ]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
 \usepackage{hypcap}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
 \usepackage{bidiftnxtra}
 \usepackage{tocloft}

 \renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip10pt}
 \renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip12pt}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

 \setmainlanguage{arabic}

 \setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
 \let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
 \title{\RL{\Huge كتاب عربي}}
 \author{\RL{}}
 \date{\RL{}}
 \rightfootnoterule

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
 \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\@arabic\c@chapter}
 \renewcommand{\thepart}{\@arabic\c@part}
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 هذا كتاب مكتوب بالعربي كاملا ولا يحوي سوى الحرف العربي
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, maybe you could complete your code so that people can try to compile it and see what is wrong. It might also help people help you, if you minimize your code (i.e. remove all lines which have nothing to do with your problem, and which are not crucial for compiling the document)

Comment: Thanks!, I am new to LaTex in general, and all commands used in header are Arabic-related, so I am not sure which might be problematic or missing, that's why I am including the full header :)

Comment: Not a problem and generally a good idea. What you could still do, is remove line-by-line and re-compile it, until you find either the solution to you issue, or a shorter version of the code that still causes the same problem.

Comment: I'm on phone right now, so I'll just suggest some packages . First make  polyglossia and bidi packages  the last packages loaded, and load arabxetex package. Then see if it works.

Comment: `polyglossia` will load `fontspec` and `bidi` automatically. Not likely to be related, but `hyperref` should be loaded last except for any packages which you particularly know need to be loaded after (e.g. `cleveref`).

Comment: @mostafax80 `arabxetex` also loads `fontspec` and `bidi`. Is this compatible with `polyglossia`? How well does it work with unicode input? (That seems not to be the main point of the package, although I've only skimmed the first few pages of the documentation, so my impression might be mistaken.)

Comment: But probably `bidi` needs to be after `hyperref`?

Comment: @mostafax80 moved as you suggested and fixed error messages, but nothing changed.

Comment: @cfr things are compiled perfectly with this header and hyperref works as intended, the only missing part is being able to open the book Right-To-Left in PDF, I am a lot puzzled since I moved things around several times and nothing changed!

Comment: @cfr yes, I said polyglossia should be the last as it contains bidi package ( just because the bidi package)  . And as you said he should remove bidi package, about whether polyglossia is compatible with arabxetex or not I haven't tried working on Arabic documents before I just red some documents in the past about how it works . However I will make one soon, so I'll read the relevant documents when I get home.

Comment: @mostafax80 Yes, I know you said it. I was just qualifying my comment about `hyperref` after looking at `bidi`'s documentation.

Comment: `bidi2in1`, mentioned in the documentation for `bidi`, looks like a first (and buggy) step in the direction of what you want.  But for documents which will be read on screen, it doesn’t make much sense to force readers to page down to the first page.  And for printing, isn’t this just a variation on the usual process of imposition?

Comment: @Thérèse It's not a big deal on screen as you said, however annoying, but in printing, NO, sending my 600 page book directly to printer prints the pages messed up with incorrect verso-recto display, inconsistent with any "Real" Arabic ONLY book.

Comment: My suggestion wasn’t to send the PDF to the printer as is, but rather to send it after imposition (look up the `imposition` tag to see what I mean).

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you, I didn't get it at first, could you supply an example?

Comment: Not now (the new semester is starting…).  And it’s hard to check solutions without the right kind of printer, because they all look strange on screen.  You also need to know what size paper the printer will use.  I’ll note only that the dummy text generator at http://justanotherfoundry.com can handle Arabic, which makes it easier to produce test files.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but Oh well...

I believe you want to pass the option `pdfdirection=R2L` to the `hyperref` package. You can also specify `pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight` to show facing pages.

This preamble creates an A5 R2L document that will open correctly in Adobe Reader (other PDF readers may not work).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight,pdfdirection=R2L]{hyperref}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

When I open the resulting PDF up in Adobe Reader, I get this (the Arabic is some random lorem ipsum from the web):

[image]

As far as the imposition discussion in the comments above, you should leave this to your printer. So long as they know that it's meant to use right-edge binding, they will do it correctly.

You can create a simple 2up booklet using `pdfbook`:

```
pdfbook --signature* '4' R2L.pdf
```

where `--signature*` (as opposed to the default `--signature`) specifies you want right-edge binding.

But this is unsuitable for a 600 page book.